# Why does time.Now().UnixNano() returns the same result after an IO operation?

Tags: windows, go, time

I use `time.Now().UnixNano()` to calculate the execution time for some part of my code, but I find an interesting thing. The elapsed time is sometimes zero after an IO operation! What's wrong with it?

The code is running in Go 1.11, and use the standard library `"time"`. Redis library is `"github.com/mediocregopher/radix.v2/redis"`. The redis server version is 3.2. I'm running this on Windows, with VSCode Editor.

```golang
isGatherTimeStat = false
if rand.Intn(100) < globalConfig.TimeStatProbability { // Here I set TimeStatProbability 100
    isGatherTimeStat = true
}
if isGatherTimeStat {
    timestampNano = time.Now()
}
globalLogger.Info("time %d", time.Now().UnixNano())
resp := t.redisConn.Cmd("llen", "log_system")
globalLogger.Info("time %d", time.Now().UnixNano())
if isGatherTimeStat {
    currentTimeStat.time = time.Since(timestampNano).Nanoseconds()
    currentTimeStat.name = "redis_llen"
    globalLogger.Info("redis_llen time sub == %d", currentTimeStat.time)
    select {
    case t.chTimeStat <- currentTimeStat:
    default:
    }
}
```

Here are some logs:

```
[INFO ][2019-07-31][14:47:53] time 1564555673269444200
[INFO ][2019-07-31][14:47:53] time 1564555673269444200
[INFO ][2019-07-31][14:47:53] redis_llen time sub == 0
[INFO ][2019-07-31][14:47:58] time 1564555678267691700
[INFO ][2019-07-31][14:47:58] time 1564555678270689300
[INFO ][2019-07-31][14:47:58] redis_llen time sub == 2997600
[INFO ][2019-07-31][14:48:03] time 1564555683268195600
[INFO ][2019-07-31][14:48:03] time 1564555683268195600
[INFO ][2019-07-31][14:48:03] redis_llen time sub == 0
[INFO ][2019-07-31][14:48:08] time 1564555688267631100
[INFO ][2019-07-31][14:48:08] time 1564555688267631100
[INFO ][2019-07-31][14:48:08] redis_llen time sub == 0
```

Comment: Which hardware architecture are you running on?

Comment: Are you running this on Windows?

Comment: @icza Yes, it's running on Windows.

Comment: @icza In the VSCode Editor actually.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. On windows the resolution of time is often higher than 1 ms. Meaning if you query the actual time twice within a millisecond, you often get the same value. Your operation sometimes yields `t = 2997600ns = 0.3μs`, which could explain this. Blame it on Windows.

Comment: @Flimzy 64bit version of Windows 10.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21262821/13860 https://stackoverflow.com/q/3744032/13860

Comment: @icza You are right! I run it on Linux, and there is no zero result. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code. On Windows, the system time is often only updated once every 10-15 ms or so, which means if you query the current time twice within this period, you get the same value.

Your operation sometimes yields `t = 2997600ns = 3ms`, which could explain this. Blame it on Windows.

Related questions:

[How precise is Go's time, really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610459/how-precise-is-gos-time-really)

[How to determine the current Windows timer resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262821/how-to-determine-the-current-windows-timer-resolution)

[Measuring time differences using System.currentTimeMillis()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062345/measuring-time-differences-using-system-currenttimemillis/13062443#13062443)

Comment: The system time has 100 ns precision, but it's only updated by the system timer interrupt every 15 ms or so. The timer resolution can be lowered to a millisecond or less, but this affects the scheduler and causes a significant increase in power consumption. If we need to measure precise intervals, as opposed to logging a system timestamp, we use the system performance counter instead, i.e. whatever way Go exposes WINAPI `QueryPerformanceCounter`.

Answer (score 0):

`time.Now()` resolution under Windows has been improved in Go 1.16, see [#8687](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8687#issuecomment-694504144) and CL [#248699](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/248699/).

The timer resolution should now be around ~500 nanoseconds.

Test program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func timediff() int64 {
    t0 := time.Now().UnixNano()
    for {
        t := time.Now().UnixNano()
        if t != t0 {
            return t - t0
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    var ds []int64
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        ds = append(ds, timediff())
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v nanoseconds\n", ds)
}
```

Test output:

```
[527400 39200 8400 528900 17000 16900 8300 506300 9700 34100] nanoseconds
```