# assign a double value to timer interval

Tags: c#, types, timer, int, double

I am trying to assign a huge number of (milliseconds) to a timer interval, but i got this crash on "timer.Enabled = true" line !

The Exception Says :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Number must be either non-negative and less than or equal to Int32.MaxValue or -1.

This is my code:

```
    CurrencyTimer.Interval = 2626086891.0;
    CurrencyTimer.Enabled = true;
    CurrencyTimer.AutoReset = true;
    CurrencyTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(TimerWorker);
    CurrencyTimer.Start();
```

The Exception point to this line : CurrencyTimer.Enabled = true;
Thanks,

Comment: You want to wait for `30` days???? `2626086891/1000/60/60/24 = 30...`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: And 9 hours, 28 minutes ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the data type of System.Timers.Timer.Interval a double?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610611/why-is-the-data-type-of-system-timers-timer-interval-a-double)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception (and [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.timers.timer.interval(v=vs.110).aspx)) is fairly clear about that the interval has to be between 0 and `int.MaxValue`. So, don't assign a value larger than that.

For very long timer intervals you may have to split your interval in shorter intervals and count yourself. I'd also be curious why you think you need a 30-day timer interval ...

Comment: but the interval type is double !

Comment: you should use schedulers in windows instead or some kind of schedulers like that @Qutaiba

Comment: Reading the docs sometimes helps. _The value must be greater than zero, and less than or equal to Int32.MaxValue_

Comment: @Qutaiba: So what? An array index is also an `int` and the valid values are only a subset of the full range. That's not unusual at all.

Comment: @Steve yes i know that, but the interval type is double !

Comment: @Qutaiba oh well, then look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610611/why-is-the-data-type-of-system-timers-timer-interval-a-double

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Threading.Timer
```

The constructor has several overloads two of which accept TimeSpan or Int64 values. The documentation does not mention limits on the values except for the intrinsic limitations of the data types.